# CakePHP Master/Detail Form - simple Issue

Tags: forms, cakephp, master-detail

I'm building a simple master/detail edit form using Cake, but can't get the values from the details records to populate the form.

Workorder -> Master
WorkorderIssues -> Detail

DebugKit tells me the data is being returned properly from both the master and detail tables.

I can populate the form with master data just fine using:

Form->input('workorder_ref');?>

..but the same approach doesn't work for the detail data:

Form->input('WorkorderIssues.issue_owner');?>

**Post data:**

Workorder(array)
workorder_id 1
workorder_ref 9212

WorkorderIssues(array)
0(array)
issue_id 1
issue_workorder_id 1
issue_owner shaun

I would appreciate some help..it's probably something simple I'm overlooking.

Many Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: Add some samples. of what you have tried, it will make it easier to diagnose.  Thanks

Comment: Lars - thanks for taking a minute to look. My problem was (as usual) syntax. To access the associated data, I successfully used Form->input('workorderissues.n.fieldname');  Have a good day.

Comment: I am glad you found your answer but please, make sure to add your notes as an answer and mark it that way so the questions does not hang around forever in unanswered state.

Answer (score 0):

The context of the question was an edit form for master/detail records with a *hasMany* association from Workorder to WorkorderIssue.

**Master data** from the request can be accessed as usual like:
form->input('fieldname'); There is only one record.

In my example, the master data (Workorder) is accessed as:

form->input('workorder_num');

Multiple records from the **Associated/detail data** can be accessed from the request as:

form->input('workorderissue.0.issue_description');

form->input('workorderissue.0.issue_owner');

form->input('workorderissue.1.issue_description');

form->input('workorderissue.1.issue_owner');

form->input('workorderissue.2.issue_description');

form->input('workorderissue.2.issue_owner');

...the integer index (0,1,2) represents the array element each record is stored under.